# Eliminar registro de la Base de datos desde el front

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, api

buenas a todos, tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo esta funcion la cual me retorna las transacciones de una API(que tengo almacenadas en una db)

```
async function getTransactionsFromApi(){
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/transactions');
const transactions = await response.json();
return transactions;}
```

Luego tengo esta funcion, que basicamente me dibuja una fila de tabla para cada una de las transacciones(VEASE, que allí le creo a cada transaccion el boton de ELIMINAR)

```
async function addRowTransactionTable(transactions){
getTransactionsFromApi();
console.log(transactions)
const transactionTable = document.getElementById("tbodyTable");
const row = transactionTable.insertRow(-1);
const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
const cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
const cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
const cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
const cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
const cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
let botonEliminar = document.createElement("button");
let botonEliminarconTexto = botonEliminar.innerText = `<button id='boton_eliminar' name='boton_eliminar' onclick='eliminarRegistro()'>Eliminar</button>`

cell1.innerHTML = transactions.id;
cell2.innerHTML = transactions.type;
cell3.innerHTML = transactions.description;
cell4.innerHTML = transactions.price;    
cell5.innerHTML = transactions.category;
cell6.innerHTML = transactions.date;
cell7.innerHTML = botonEliminarconTexto;

if(transactions.type == 'Egreso'){
    cell2.style.background = 'Red';
    cell2.style.color = 'white';
} else
    cell2.style.background = 'Green';
    cell2.style.color = 'white';

return botonEliminarconTexto}
```

Esta funcion se encargaría de dibujar lo anterior para cada transaccion

```
async function drawTable(transactions){
const tbodyTable = document.getElementById("tbodyTable").innerHTML= "";
transactions.forEach(transaction => {
    addRowTransactionTable(transaction);
});}
```

Y ESTA, es la que tengo problemas..
Basicamente no se como relacionar para que al apretar cada boton ELIMINAR me elimine esa transaccion de la base de datos.. lo cual llamaria a otra funcion(refreshtable) la cual refresca todas las transacciones que hay en la base de datos y ya no la mostraria.
El problema es que no se como vincular ese boton eliminar para que al apretarlo, me mande la ID que tiene la transaccion correspondiente a su fila a la API y allí ejecutar una QUERY para mandar a la base de datos

```
async function eliminarRegistro(){
const boton = addRowTransactionTable();
console.log(boton)
console.log(transactions)
const element = document.getElementById(`trans_${transactions.id}`);
const fila = element.parentNode.parentNode
await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/transactions/:${transactions.id}`, { method: 'DELETE' });
fila.innerHTML = 'Eliminacion Exitosa';
refreshTable();}
```

Esta es mi funcion en la API para ejecutar el DELETE y recibir la id

```
app.delete('/transactions/:id', (req, res) => {
const transactionId = req.params.id;
const selectedTransaction = req.body.filter(transaction => transaction.transactionId == transactionId)
res.send(selectedTransaction);
```

})